# Sending messages from server to all clients

Tags: java, sockets, server, client

I've created a chat program, but I can't figure out one little aspect. The way it works now is like this:

Server starts

Client 1 connects

Client 2 connects

Client 1 sends message: hello.

Server gets the message and sends it to all connected clients.

The main problem I'm having is the server sends Client 1's message to Client 1 as well so there's now 2 "hello"'s instead of just 1.

Here's my Server.java

```
for (Iterator<DataOutputStream> e = clients.iterator(); e.hasNext(); ) {
      DataOutputStream dout = (DataOutputStream)e.next();

      dout.writeUTF(message);
 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, change the `clients list` type into `Socket`

```
static List<Socket> clients = new ArrayList<Socket>();
```

Then, create a public variable with type `Socket` to hold the sender client.

```
private static Socket senderSocket;
```

After that, replace this:

```
Socket s = ss.accept();
System.out.println( "Connection from " + s );
DataOutputStream dout = new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
clients.add(dout);
```

with this:

```
Socket s = ss.accept();
System.out.println( "Connection from "+s );
//DataOutputStream dout = new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
clients.add(s);
```

Finally, change the `for` loop:

```
for (Iterator<DataOutputStream> e = clients.iterator(); e.hasNext();)
```

into:

```
for(Socket s : clients)
```

And, in every `client` create the `DataOutputStream` and write your message. **And, of course, here you should skip the client which equals the sender in its Socket.**

Comment: The checking part is crucial, as there may be cases there are 1000's event 100's of 1000 users on different cases. So a checking of every client O(n) should be avoided. A broadcast message is in O(1) and check filter should not create any overhead.  May be this discussion is not straight away applicable to this question. But one should also consider design choices of keep the client being intelligent to ignore its own message as well.

Comment: Yes, he could assign a code for each client to be send by the client with the message; and when the replied message came with it's own id, he could ignore it. You are right idea is in design; my answer was based on his code, that he posted in the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

There's many ways to solve this issue. If you're writing strings across the network, you could simply create a parse-able string containing the username(or some other unique identifier) and message, with a divider that you can do .split() on.

If you're writing Objects, you could create a Message class that contains a string (the message) and a unique identifier, like a username or IP, then write that across.

When your server gets either, just check if the origin == the destination, and don't send it.

---

Or, don't send the message to yourself in the first place. If you send "Hello" as a message, only send it out, so when you get it back, you can then display it.